# Not able to see Axis2 Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, apache-axis

Here's the problem: 
I tried with multiple Eclipse IDE versions.

> eclipse-jee-galileo-SR1-win32 
>  eclipse-jee-galileo-SR2-win32 
>   eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32  
>  eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32

Axis2 runtime is axis2-1.6.1

Axis2 Plugin from http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/index.html

> org.apache.axis2.eclipse.service.plugin_1.6.1.jar 
>   org.apache.axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin_1.6.1.jar

Tried putting above jars into either dropins or plugin directories, but not able to see Axis2 Wizard under File -> New -> Other (for all of the above eclipse IDEs).

Answer (score 2):

There was indeed an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5145) with the 1.6.1 versions of the plugins. You can use 1.6.0 or one of the [snapshot builds](https://builds.apache.org/job/Axis2/lastStableBuild/).

Comment: I've tried Axis2 plugin 1.6.0 with Helios and Indigo, and it does work either. The WSDL generation has an exception on the last step of the wizard: `An error occurred while completing process - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` The code generation creates a file on the file system, but there is nothing in it. I'm on a MacBookPro, latest version of Java. I'm in transit right now, but I can dig up more details later if you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply the batch provided [HERE](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-5145?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

Answer (score 1):

I also got thru though the 1.4.1 was able to show up axis2 wizard for 
Eclipse Indigo Service Release 2, Build id: 20120216-1857
Java 7 x86 32bit

But, picked up the latest snapshot 1.7.0 version: [axis2.eclipse.service.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar](https://builds.apache.org/job/Axis2/lastStableBuild/org.apache.axis2%24axis2.eclipse.service.plugin/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2.eclipse.service.plugin/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/axis2.eclipse.service.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar) and  [axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar](https://builds.apache.org/job/Axis2/lastStableBuild/org.apache.axis2%24axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin/1.7.0-SNAPSHOT/axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a problem with `org.apache.axis2.eclipse.service.plugin_1.6.1`
and `org.apache.axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin_1.6.1 plugins`.

When I dropped under dropins folder in **eclipse-jee-indigo**-SR1-win32-x86_64.
It didn't work.

As mentioned above I downloaded and used 1.6.2 axis2 plugins and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After googling around for few hours. I figure it out that Axis2 Plug-in for Version 1.6.1 have bug on apache axis2 mailing list.

Looks like version 1.4 also have bug! didn't check whether it got fixed or not.

i used version 1.3 for Axis2 codegen & service-archieve from:
http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/axis2/tools/1_3/[enter link description here](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/axis2/tools/1_3/)

It worked well with eclipse-jee-indigo-SR1-win32.

Unzip the downloaded archives and put into /plugins,

Comment: If you are using Axis2 1.6.1 as runtime, then you should not use the 1.3 versions of the plugins. Instead use 1.6.0 or 1.6.2-SNAPSHOT as indicated in my response.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, but I tried Axis2 1.3 as well and it doesn't work either - that is, I can't see it from File > New > Other. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, after installing Axis2 1.6.1 for Eclipse Indigo. Did not find the Axis wizards in eclipse.

Thanks to Andreas Veithen's answer above, I was able to fix the problem.

Just install the SNAPSHOT versions from the link below,

https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/axis2/axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin/SNAPSHOT/

You will need to download only 2 jars from here:

- axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin-SNAPSHOT.jar
- axis2.eclipse.service.plugin-SNAPSHOT.jar

Save it to your eclipse/plugins directory. Open eclipse and ctrl+n, you will find the Axis wizards!

Answer (score 0):

You will need this jar file and you can download this jar file from this [link](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/axis2/tools/1_4/). After that you  can download these files
 1- axis2-eclipse-codegen-wizard-1.4.zip
 2- axis2-eclipse-service-archiver-wizard-1.4.zip

Unzip both files  and then copy all directories Axis2_Codegen_Wizard_1.3.0 and    Axis2_Service_Archiver_1.3.0  in Eclipse plugins directory.

Eclipse plugins directory (Axis2_Codegen_Wizard_1.3.0 and    Axis2_Service_Archiver_1.3.0 already copied)

Now start the eclipse and then go to File-->New--> Others and then expand "Axis2 Wizards". Here you will find the Eclipse Axis2 Code generator and Service Archiver wizards.

After that restart your IDE  you can find your AXIX2

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue using Spring Tool Suite (on top of Eclipse) and had to place my jar files into the spring (STS) dropin folder.

(I used the following jar files in my situation org.apache.axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin_1.6.2.jar & org.apache.axis2.eclipse.service.plugin_1.6.2.jar)